# how to map a json when I don't know the names of the parameters and their number in java using rest template?

Tags: java, json, spring, mapping, resttemplate

How to map a json to a class using rest template when I don't know the names of the fruits or their quantities? Because I can have for example only 1 or 150 fruits.

```
{
    "Apple": 14656,
    "Orange": 4813,
    "Banana": 1722,
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I tried to map it to this class, but I don't know what name to give it in jsonproperty

```
public class OpenFruitsDto {

    private final String name;
    private final int amount;

    OpenGitHubRepositoryNameDto(@JsonProperty( ? ) String name, @JsonProperty(?) int amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can define `Map<String, Integer>` as parameter type for rest template.

Comment: Does your data can be in an `json array` instead? {["Apple": 14656,
    "Orange": 4813,
    "Banana": 1722...]}

Answer (score 0):

You can map your object to a [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) in case you're not sure about the json structure of your input.